# Mixed-Integer Bilinear Program (MIBLP) with linear constraints

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, binary-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Consider the problem of

\begin{align}
\min_{x,y} \quad &a^Tx + b^Ty + x^TQy \\
&Ax \leq d \\
&Cy \leq e \\
&x_i \in \mathbb{R} \quad i \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\} \\
&y_i \in {\{0,1\}} \quad i \in \{1,2,\ldots,M\}
\end{align}
where $x = [x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N]^T$ and $y = [y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_N]^T$. Is it possible to find optimum (local/global) solution to this Mixed-Integer Bilinear Program (MIBLP). Is there any solver for this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1. [Linearize $z_{i,j}=x_i y_j$](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/05/multiplication-of-continuous-and-binary.html) and you can solve this as a standard MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) problem.
2. If the problem is convex use a standard MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) solver (e.g. Cplex, Gurobi)
3. If the problem is non-convex use a global solver (Cplex has a [global MIQP solver](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes126/newNonconvexMIQP.html), some other global MINLP solvers are Baron, Couenne, Antigone).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have some question. 1- Is there any paper that explains in details why that linearization is true? 2- After linearization, we can find the exact optimal solution using MIP, right? Or it is an approximation because the linearization is not exact? 3- To me, it seems both the first and the third method you suggested should work. What is the difference?

Comment: I checked the transformation. I think it is exact.

Comment: The linearization is exact. The main issue is to avoid very large bounds as they can lead to numerical trouble.

Comment: I didn't get. You mean if the continuous variable belongs to for example [0,1], it is okay?

Comment: Big M's of the form 1000000000 are notorious for giving bad results in MIP models.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you also tell me your opinion about my third question in the comment?

Comment: The difference? I don't know what to answer on this except to say It is a different approach. For many practical problems there are different ways to solve them.

Comment: Is it possible to do the linearization if we have $f(x,y,\delta) = \delta \max{\{x,y\}}$ where $x, y \in [0,1]$ and $\delta \in \{0,1\}$?

Comment: I asked it as a separate question because it wasn't related to this topic. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915757/linearization-of-a-non-linear-objective-function