# Linearization of a non-linear objective function

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, binary-programming

Consider the optimization problem 
\begin{align}
&\min_{x_1,x_2,y_1, y_2,\delta_1, \delta_2} \delta_1 \max{\{x_1,y_1\}} +
\delta_2 \max{\{x_2,y_2\}} \\
&x_1,x_2, y_1,y_2 \in[0,1] \\
&\delta_1, \delta_2 \in \{0,1\} \\
&\begin{bmatrix} e_1\\e_2
\end{bmatrix} \leq A\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2
\end{bmatrix} +B\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\y_2
\end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix}
c_1\\c_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
&1\leq a \delta_1 + b\delta_2 \leq d
 \end{align}
Is it possible to linearize the objective function so that we can use a MILP solver?

Comment: Ummm: the objective is $0$ when $\delta = 0$, and is never negative, so...

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh my bad. It wasn't the actual problem. I edited the question. They are more constraints. But they are linear. The only problem is with the objective function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely rewritten answer since the OP has changed the problem.

Let $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ be continuous variables.  Then

$\min z_{1}+z_{2}$

subject to

$z_{1} \geq x_{1} - (1-\delta_{1})$

$z_{1} \geq y_{1} - (1-\delta_{1})$

$z_{2} \geq x_{2} - (1-\delta_{2})$

$z_{2} \geq y_{2} - (1-\delta_{2})$

$z_{1}, z_{2} \geq 0$

These constraints ensure that if $\delta_{i}=1$, then $z_{i}$ is greater than or equal to the maximum of $x_{i}$ and $y_{i}$.  If $\delta_{i}=0$, then the constraints ensure that $z_{i} \geq 0$.  When $z_{i}$ is minimized, it will take on the smallest possible value.

Comment: In the original question, only $\delta$ was 0-1 variable. $x,y$ are continuous variables belonging to $[0,1]$.

Comment: See the revised answer.

Comment: It seems correct to me.